# Does "amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib " support large messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, jms, amazon-sqs

I am using [AsyncMessageReceiver.java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/code-examples.html#example-asynchronous-message-receiver) sample program from AWS documentation to consume messages added to a SQS queue. If I send a message via the AWS console, the sample program is working fine.

However if I send a large message (> 256 KB. Using amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib) my message receiver program is not being notified. From the AWS console, I could see that the large messages sent are available in the queue.

Is there any limitation in using "amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib" for large messages?